# C# What is a type of System.Object[*]?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a COM DLL with a function that should be returning an array of objects of a type that is dependant on the arguments passed in.

I know what the return type should be, but what is returned is of type System.Object[*]

Despite searching I have no idea how to cast that to anything useful. Simply trying to cast to the type it should be "someType[]" fails, also casting to System.Object[] fails.  What does the * mean in this context in C#?

Comment: Please show it in context. C# or C++.

Comment: Never seen that, unless `*` means `dynamic`. Show a screenshot.

Comment: You posted an invalid piece of code, so elaborate. What is your source (documentation)?

Comment: It is a non-conformant array, its lower-bound doesn't start at 0.  Not unusual in COM, the next most popular choice is 1.  You'll have to use the Array class to access the array.  Use its GetLower/UpperBound() method to discover valid indices, use GetValue() to retrieve an element.

Comment: @HansPassant is right. I'm guessing I can't accept a comment as the answer?

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you mean casting to System.Object[] fails compile-time. Try casting this way:

```
someType[] myObj = (someType[]) (System.Object) theDllObj.theDllCall();
```

It's a cast-via-Object-trick I've used many times when the compiler is being grumpy.

Comment: So where is the `*` ?

Comment: That is an important assumption. Ask the OP first :)

Comment: Actually it's failing at run-time. Throws an exception. Interesting trick though, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Changed to cast to someType[], which is the array type OP wants. I'm trying to avoid/ignore the weird Object[*] return type

Comment: Ah.. if it fails runtime this will probably not work...